# Ribbon workbench URL Command Action Parameter Guid

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2016, crm-ribbon-workbench

I have a an adress of a dialog form: ...ntityName=opportunity&ObjectId=%wwwww-www-wwww-wwww-wwwwwwww%7d     and I want to call this dialog form from a button. I create a button for this and a parameter data in ribbon but and I don't know how to use the parameter data wich the id in the adress: [image]

Comment: any answer for my question plz?

Comment: why create a button and not call the dialog directly form the execute workflow button?

Answer (score -2):

You can use a javascript Action, you can put any data or parameters you want.

the javascript funtion to use is:

```
Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId()
```